# Freya vs Luna performance requirement

Tags: release-freya, luna, performance

I have a netbook with small performance (*AMD C-70 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics x 2*) with 1.7 GiB of memory. Elementary Luna is already quite slow. If I update to Freya, shall I expect lower or higher performance?

Comment: I have never used Luna on a real machine (only virtual ones), but from hear-say I'd say the performance with Freya will be somewhat worse on very low-end machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, Freya will have lower performance. I have not a single fact but I remember the "exposé effect" much smoother in Luna that in Freya, for example.